# iOS SwiftUI - PhotosPicker getting mime type from selected file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using this code to pick video or image using PhotosPicker:

```
PhotosPicker(
    selection: $selectedItem,
    matching: matching: .any(of: [.images, .videos]),
    photoLibrary: .shared()) {
        Text("edit")
            .padding(.horizontal, 18)
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
            .cornerRadius(12)
    }
    .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
        Task {
            if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                selectedFileData = data
                // mimeType = ???
                          
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I find out the mime Type from the selected file? I know how to get it when I have the path/url of the selected file but I don't know how to get it with PhotosPicker either

Answer (score 3):

Struggling with the same issue.

It looks like we can access `var supportedContentTypes: [UTType] { get }` from `PhotosPickerItem`

> The content types the item supports in order of the most preferred to the least.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospickeritem/4022920-supportedcontenttypes

```
item.supportedContentTypes.first?.preferredMIMEType // Optional("image/jpeg")
```

Better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score -1):

By passing the reference URL path to this method you can get picked image or video MIME type

```
func mimeTypeForPath(path: String) -> String {
  let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
  let pathExtension = url.pathExtension

  if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension! as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() {
     if let mimetype = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() {
            return mimetype as String
     }
  }
    return "image/png"
}
```

I hope it may help you...

Comment: As I said in the question. I don't know how to get the file URL path

Answer (score -2):

I found a way. You can check item supported type and custom handle. Try replace your Task in onChange to this:

```
Task {
    if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
        selectedFileData = data
    }
    guard let type = newItem?.supportedContentTypes.first else {
        print("There is no supported type")
    }
    if type.conforms(to: UTType.image) {
        // Handle any image type
    } else if type.conforms(to: UTType.video) {
        // Handle video type
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).